# Convert list to a particular format [(123, 123), (345,875)..]

Tags: python-3.x, list, format, parentheses

I have the following list:

`l = [12, 23,54, 67, 87,98,15, 90, 44,81]`

I would like to convert them into pairs with parenthesis. Desired output should look like  the following:

`[(12, 23),(54, 67), (87,98),(15, 90), (44,81)]`

What I tried so far?

`print('{}'.format(' '.join('({},)'.format(i) for i in l)))`

This does not print the list as pairs. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why, out of interest? This seems like something that might be better served with a dictionary, but it's hard to tell without a use case

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [12, 23,54, 67, 87,98,15, 90, 44,81]
my=[]
for i in range(0,len(l),2):
    my.append(tuple(l[i:i+2]))
print(my)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `for i in l`, you'd need to use a range to allow you to set an increment by which to step through. range takes 3 arguments - a starting number, an end number, and (optionally; it defaults to 1) an increment.

Something like this:
`tuple_list = [(l[i], l[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]`